# Random batch generator Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, queue

I want to develop a random batch generation by queueing my data (x_data and y_target)  in Tensorflow. Here my code:

```
x_data=np.asarray(x_data) # shape (2404,60,41,2)
y_target=np.asarray(y_data) # shape (2404,7)

queue_x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[20,60,41,2])
queue_y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[20,7])
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=50, dtypes=[tf.float64,tf.int64], shapes=[(60,41,2), (7)])
init = q.enqueue_many([queue_x_data, queue_y_target])
dequeue_op = q.dequeue()
data_batch, target_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(dequeue_op,batch_size=32,num_threads=4,capacity=50000, min_after_dequeue=10000)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
  curr_data_batch, curr_target_batch = sess.run([data_batch, target_batch])
```

Here I would try just to print the generated batch.

```
  print(curr_data_batch)
  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

But I am not able to get any generated batch printed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons.

- First, you never called the `init` operation: `sess.run(init, {queue_x_data: x_data, queue_y_target: y_target}))`.
- Second, `min_after_dequeue=10000` is to high compare to the number of elements in the queue, try to set it to a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

You try to fill your queue from placeholders, but placeholders must be filling with data by transfer `free_dict` parameters then you call `sess.run()`